# What are the similarities / differences between Control.Observable and Control.Event modules in F#?

Tags: events, haskell, f#

F# (at least in Visual Studio 2012) has both [`Control.Observable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370313(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Control.Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340422(v=vs.110).aspx).

- How are they related?
- Which one should be used when?
- Are there performance differences between the two?

---

I would also love to know what Haskell modules / packages / features the .NET `IEnumerable` / `IObservable` duality achieved with *reactive extensions to .NET* correspond to.

Comment: The reactive extensions to .NET correspond to the principles of Functional Reactive programming, and there are [many packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:frp) that implement this functionality in Haskell.

Comment: @dflemstr would you especially recommend any from that long list?

Comment: [`reactive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive) is the first popular FRP implementation, so it is stable and has a lot of functionality. However, I prefer [`reactive-banana`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) because it has a more modern design and better API in my opinion. If you have performance-critical applications like games, [`elerea`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/elerea) is a good choice too; it only implements `Signal` and not `Event` (two important FRP concepts), so it might be foreign to Reactive.NET (which only implements `Event`s afaik) users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, there is a number of differences between `IEvent` and `IObservable`. The reason why there are two similar types is that `IEvent` has been designed for F# (earlier and it is left there mostly for compatibility reasons) and the `IObservable` type was added later on to the .NET (and so F# added support for it too). Here are some differences:

- `IEvent` does not support *removing* of event handlers, so when you create a processing pipeline (combining `map`, `filter` and others) and then call `RemoveHandler` on the resulting event, it leaves some handlers attached (yes, that's a leak and [we wrote a more detailed paper about it](http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/hollywood/))
  On the other hand `IObservable` is able to remove handlers.
- As a result of the previous point, `IObservable` behaves differently with respect to stateful combinators. For example, when you use `Event.scan`, you can attach multiple handlers to the resulting event and they will see the same state. `IObservable` creates a "new state" for every attached handler (unless you use subject explicitly).

In practical F# programming, this means:

- You should generally prefer `IObservable` if you want to be able to remove event handlers (using `RemoveHandler` or when using `AwaitObservable` in F# async workflows).
- If you want to declare events (usable from C#) then you need to create properties of type `IEvent` and so you need to use `Event` combinators.

As mentioned in comments, the F# model is heavily influenced by functional reactive programming (FRP) which is an idea that was first developed in Haskell, so you should find a plenty of similar libraries. The F# version is "less pure" in order to be more practical for .NET programming.

Comment: link to the paper is dead.

Comment: @devouredelysium I've updated the link to the paper. In case the link ever breaks again, the title is "Collecting Hollywood's Garbage: Avoiding Space-Leaks in Composite Events".