# How does Reactive Framework differ from F# Events?

Tags: f#, reactive-programming

If I'm familiar with F# events already, and I don't plan to have too much C# interop, are there significant reasons to consider using the Reactive Framework?

Comment: This reads like a Gorilla v Shark question - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: Here's a [possibly helpful post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/2019a946-5238-4527-80e5-4bce8d931f77).

Comment: @JohnPalmer It's a genuine question. There's very little documentation on either of these things. It's also very plausible, given F#'s history as a test bed for features that eventually made it in to C#, that the differences are only syntactic and legacy.

Comment: I'm not an expert on F# in any way, but I thought that F# used `IObservable<T>` for the basis of its event system. If that's the case they are one and the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there are two main differences:

- Firstly, there is a difference between the `IEvent<'T>` interface (and functions in the `Event` module) and the `IObservable<'T>` interface (used by functions from the `Observable` module and Reactive Fx). The difference [has been discussed on SO earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747861/what-are-the-similarities-differences-between-control-observable-and-control-e).
- Reactive Framework is a more complex library, so it implements many combinators that are not available in F# in `Observable` or `Event` modules (although there is a [open-source project that adds many of them](http://trelford.com/blog/post/MiniRx.aspx))

The summary is, you should prefer functions from the `Observable` module. If it has everything you need, there is no need for Reactive Framework. If it does not, then you'll need either Reactive Framework or MiniRx (which, I believe, is sometimes more efficient too).

The F# `Event` module [dates back to 2006](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/03/24/559582.aspx), so I think Reactive Framework is clearly inspired by that, but it does not fully replace the F# functionality (mainly because it is not standard part of .NET or F# core).

Comment: Actually, it looks like [IEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340439.aspx) now inherits IObservable

Comment: Speaking of open source implementation, it's worth mentioning also FSharp.Reactive on GitHub, which wraps most (all?) of Rx extensions in a F#-friendly manner: https://github.com/panesofglass/FSharp.Reactive